# How do I compile Readline support into Ruby

Tags: ruby, readline, irb

My version of ruby was compiled with `editline` (on os x) and I miss the features of `readline` in `irb`.

How do I recompile ruby with `readline` support?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Install `readline` to `/usr/local`
2. Recompile ruby from scratch and use the `--with-readline-dir=/usr/local` switch

or if you have downloaded the ruby sources earlier and built it by hand,

1. Go to the `ext/readline` folder of your ruby source tree
2. Type `ruby extconf.rb` and then run the `make && make install` procedure for ruby.

Comment: Check out http://bogojoker.com/readline/ for more information on readline in general.

Comment: Notably the 2nd set requires you to have ruby installed, which may mean compiling and installing ruby once without readline, only to recompile and reinstall again it *with* readline.  Recursive dependencies suck.

Answer (score 2):

There's also a [pure ruby readline](https://github.com/luislavena/rb-readline).

Comment: google's first result for "pure ruby readline" was the right place.