# IRB escapes UTF characters

Tags: ruby, irb

I'm using OS-X (10.10.5) and rbenv (1.0.0) Ruby (2.2.4p230) and Fish Shell (2.2.0).

When I type non ASCII characters in `irb` they are automatically escaped.

```
max@MaxBook ~/p/sandbox> echo "Ö"
Ö
max@MaxBook ~/p/sandbox> irb 
irb(main):001:0> \U+FFC3\U+FFB6
```

I though at first this could be a problem with the shell or my Terminal settings but it only happens in IRB. Changing shells or ruby versions does not effect it.

I did not have this problem on my previous laptop which had an almost identical configuration. What is going on here?

Comment: Just as a data point for you, I use rvm and in Ruby 2.3 and JRuby 9000, the character "Ö" prints out as itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable unicode support in `IRB` by recompiling Ruby against `readline` (instead of `libedit` which would be the default).

First install `readline` for example with `brew`:

```
brew install readline
```

I use `rbenv` to manage Ruby versions and use the following line to install Ruby versions:

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-readline-dir="$(brew --prefix readline)" rbenv install 2.3.1
```

With `rvm` it will look like:

```
rvm install 2.3.1 --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

Or when you might want to recompile Ruby from source, then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1781539/2483313) might help you.